# Partition disk when installing ubuntu using LVM

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, system-installation, encryption, lvm

I am trying to partition my disk when installing my ubuntu image:
What am trying to achieve is:

- Set up 3 main partitions / , /var and /home
- encrypt all 3 paritions using LVM encryption module presented by ubuntu installer.

So far i could create the 3 partitions from one part, but i can't place all 3 under the same encrypted partition. What i tried could be seen in the picture 1 below, which leads to an error if trying to install.
When i use juste 1 LVM partition and inside 1 partition, the root /, everything works fine, the problem occurs when i create a new partition table under LVM.

I also tried to create 3 LVM partitions, one for each, but it also lead to an error when booting the ubuntu. (picture 2)

Any idea how to proceed in order to create those 3 partitions under LVM encryption? could it be done during the installation of ubuntu? or afterward? or maybe before by editing the iso?

thx for any lead you can share.

(Using virtual box and ubuntu 20.04.1)

picture 1: [trying to create 3 partition under LVM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQrbP.png)

picture 2: [3 LVM partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdE82.png)

Comment: did you find an answer